# Mravinsky mumbles

Tags: грамматика

In [this clip](http://youtu.be/fR_r22oxEh4?t=8m5s) (starting at 8:05), Russian conductor Mravinsky is talking about the composer Sibelius. I can understand most of it, except for the **???** marks below:

> Но этот компоситор до сих пор один из моих любимых потому, что...тот ледяной 
>       чистоты воздух, который веет из глубин его музыкального текста. Это неповторимо, 
>       и до его не бывал, и после него, я тоже не знаю, ***таких произведений с которыми 
>       веел*** (**???**) такой хрустальной, немножко леденящей чистотой.
>
> И всегда еще в этих произведениях немножко бывает такое ощущение свежевы-**????** веска, как будто вы идете против **???** свежий дух.

In the first case, I don't understand the grammar (or I misheard it).

In the second two cases, I can't parse what he's saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the audio is not the best quality. For this reason, you find it difficult to disassemble speech.

> Но этот **композитор** до сих пор один из моих любимых, потому что тот
>   ледяной чистоты воздух, который веет из глубин его музыкального текста
>   - это неповторимо, и до него не бывало, и после него я тоже не знаю таких произведений, **от которых веяло** такой хрустальной, немножко
>   леденящей чистотой.
>
> И всегда еще в этих произведениях немножко бывает такое ощущение
>   **свежего ветерка в висках**, как будто вы идете **против ветра**. Такой вот свежий дух.

Incidentally, the last phrase mentioned in this short note: http://www.moles.ee/05/Jun/01/6-1.php

Comment: и до него не бывало